Jupyter notebook Nbextensions table of Contents(2) dislocation
As you can see in the pic, the TOC dislocation in Chrome, it is not look like this before, How can I fix it?

I've tried updating the TOC plugin, and reinstall it, like command "conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_nbextensions_configurator, and
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions"  , but it still look like this.

Which version of Jupyter are you using? Jupyter Notebook 7+ comes with the Table of Contents built in and so you don't need jupyter_contrib_nbextensions (and I suspect jupyter_nbextensions_configurator).

Thank you so much, yes it is nbextensions. Thank you for telling me that Jupyter Notebook 7+ comes with the Table of Contents built in. I uninstall the nbextensions, and use Notebook 7+ now. Great thanks!
